# Parameter limit for MS Access database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, parameters

I know that the parameter limit for Sql server is 2100. I am wondering if there is such a limit for MS Access database. Anyone knows about it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Access, but I thought that Access has no stored procedures, only named queries? If so, the answer is whatever you can fit into "approximately 64,000" characters:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-specifications-HP005186808.aspx

But it would be interesting to know why you need to know: for almost all developers almost all the time, actually encountering database capacity limits like this is a danger signal that you have design or implementation issues.

Comment: In most of cases, I don't worry about it, but I have got scalability issue here. I have groups of items to be queried. I need to run a query for selected items. All items are passed into queries through parameters. The number of groups are limited, normally not exceeding 100. The problem is that this 100 groups could contain more than 2100 items, thus causing parameter number to be over 2100.

Comment: Sounds like you should put that data in a table, and then you can join to it.

Answer (score 0):

Access 2007 doesn't allow more than 100 parameters. If you go over that limit, you will get a ***Query is too complex*** error.

I'm not sure if the situation has changed for Access 2010.